# Is it possible to make a .tar.gz file directly from stdin? Or, I need to tar together already gzipped files

Tags: tar, compression, gzip

I'm going to tell you exactly what I need in order to clarify the cryptic question in the title. I'm currently making scheduled MySQL backups of all my databases with something like:

```
mysqldump ... | gzip -c > mysql-backup.gz
```

This is ok, but I'm willing to make a separate file for each single database, since that will make it easier to take a look at dumped data or restore a single database:

```
for db in $dbs; do mysqldump ... $db | gzip -c > mysql-backup-$db.gz; done
```

I'd like to store all of the dumps for each single backup in a single `.tar` file, i.e. `mysql-backup.tar.gz` with all the dumped databases inside. I know I can simply leave `.sql` files uncompressed and then `tar -cz *.sql`, but **1) I'm searching for a way that doesn't need to temporarly store big files**. In my current script, in fact, `mysqldump` is piped into `gzip`, so no big file is created.

**2) Is there a similar way in which I can create `.tar.gz` from stdin**?

**3) Is `tar -c *.sql.gz` eqivalent to `tar -cz *.sql`?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin

Comment: @jhilmer Linked questions is about getting file names from stdin, not actual data.

Comment: _Is `tar -c *.sql.gz` eqivalent to `tar -cz *.sql`?_ - No, the latter is slightly more efficient, but that makes more of a difference for many small files rather than a few big files.

Answer (score 5):

I cobbled together some python to do what you want. It uses **python's tarfile** library to append stdin to a tar file, and then simply seeks back in the tar to rewrite the header with the right size at eof. The usage would be:

```bsh
rm -f mytar
for db in $dbs
do mysqldump ... $db | gzip -c |
   tarappend -t mytar -f mysql-backup-$db.gz
done
tar tvf mytar
```

Here's the `tarappend` python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# concat stdin to end of tar file, with given name. meuh on stackexchange
# $Id: tarappend,v 1.3 2015/07/08 11:31:18 meuh $

import sys, os, tarfile, time, copy
from optparse import OptionParser
try:
    import grp, pwd
except ImportError:
    grp = pwd = None

usage = """%prog: ... | %prog -t tarfile -f filename
Appends stdin to tarfile under the given arbitrary filename.
tarfile is created if it does not exist.\
"""

def doargs():
    parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
    parser.add_option("-f", "--filename", help="filename to use")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--tarfile", help="existing tar archive")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.filename is None or options.tarfile is None:
        parser.error("need filename and tarfile")
    if len(args):
        parser.error("unknown args: "+" ".join(args))
    return options

def copygetlen(fsrc, fdst):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst. return len"""
    totlen = 0
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(16*1024)
        if not buf:
            return totlen
        fdst.write(buf)
        totlen += len(buf)

class TarFileStdin(tarfile.TarFile):
    def addstdin(self, tarinfo, fileobj):
        """Add stdin to archive. based on addfile() """
        self._check("aw")
        tarinfo = copy.copy(tarinfo)
        buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
        bufoffset = self.offset
        self.fileobj.write(buf)
        self.offset += len(buf)

        tarinfo.size = copygetlen(fileobj, self.fileobj)
        blocks, remainder = divmod(tarinfo.size, tarfile.BLOCKSIZE)
        if remainder > 0:
            self.fileobj.write(tarfile.NUL * (tarfile.BLOCKSIZE - remainder))
            blocks += 1
        self.offset += blocks * tarfile.BLOCKSIZE
        # rewrite header with correct size
        buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
        self.fileobj.seek(bufoffset)
        self.fileobj.write(buf)
        self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
        self.members.append(tarinfo)

class TarInfoStdin(tarfile.TarInfo):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if len(name)>100:
            raise ValueError(name+": filename too long")
        if name.endswith("/"):
            raise ValueError(name+": is a directory name")
        tarfile.TarInfo.__init__(self, name)
        self.size = 99
        self.uid = os.getuid()
        self.gid = os.getgid()
        self.mtime = time.time()
        if pwd:
            self.uname = pwd.getpwuid(self.uid)[0]
            self.gname = grp.getgrgid(self.gid)[0]

def run(tarfilename, newfilename):
    tar = TarFileStdin.open(tarfilename, 'a')
    tarinfo = TarInfoStdin(newfilename)
    tar.addstdin(tarinfo, sys.stdin)
    tar.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = doargs()
    run(options.tarfile, options.filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not easily. `tar` records not only file contents, but also file metadata (name, timestamps, permissions, owner and such). That information has to come from somewhere, and it won't be there in a pipe.

You could gzip your database dumps to a file (probably named for the database in question), append the file to a tar archive and then delete the file before proceeding to the next database. That'd result in a .gz.tar file, which is unusual but in no way a problem, and probably not use significantly more disk than gzipping a whole-database dump (it will be a little less efficiently compressed since it can't share across database borders).

Answer (score 1):

No, and I miss that feature so much: [my question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587013/how-can-i-make-tar-read-input-from-stdin).

If the file to be archived is a raw file with no filesystem metadata associated to it, `tar` doesn't have neither a filename nor a path necessary to build the internal directories / files tree (to say the least).

I think that something can be done in Perl, which has some library dedicated to compression / decompression / archiving of files: see if you can get the most out of this answer: [a related answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/611017/380067).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) tar post-processor.

However, you might question the use of `tar`  and consider some other ways to archive your things. In particular consider [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) and [afio](http://members.chello.nl/~k.holtman/afio.html)

Notice that `mysqldump`  understands the `--export-all` option (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498058/841108)). You might pipe that into some script understanding the boundaries, etc...

Answer (score 0):

here's what I did, creating a tmp file (and deleting it afterwards)

```
temp=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $temp" EXIT
echo 'blabla' >$temp
tar czf - $temp
```